# Show data of table when clicking on a value - SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, wpf

Whenever I click on a name in EmployeeRank1 List listbox I want to get in the EmployeeRank1Information listbox associated data from the table for it. However, I get an exception instead. Screenshots and code used provided below.

**Table**
[image]

**WPF Window**
[image]

**Exception**
[image]

**Code I have used**

```
private void employeeRank1List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(employeeRank1List.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            // use a try-catch, in case we run into an
            // error while digging into the database
            try
            {
                // create a query and select everything from "EmployeeRank1" table
                // except the Password and GenericPassword columns
                string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = @name AND Salary = @salary AND Responsibility = @responsibility AND Position = @position AND Age = @age AND YearsInCompany = @yearsInCompany";

                // Create an SqlCommand and connect to the database
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

                // create a connection to the database and run sqlCommand
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

                // use the sqlDataAdapter
                using (sqlDataAdapter)
                {
                    // add a value to the EmployeesRank1 Information table, once an item in the EmployeesRank1 table is clicked
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", employeeRank1List.SelectedValue);

                    // create a new data table that allows us
                    // to store data from tables within objects
                    DataTable employeeRank1InformationTable = new DataTable();

                    // fill the sqlDataAdapter with all the
                    // information from the query(from the EmployeeRank1 table)
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(employeeRank1InformationTable);

                    // set the content of the employeeRank1List
                    // to be the content from each column in the table
                    employeeRank1Information.DisplayMemberPath = "Salary";
                    employeeRank1Information.DisplayMemberPath = "Position";
                    employeeRank1Information.DisplayMemberPath = "Responsibility";
                    employeeRank1Information.DisplayMemberPath = "Age";
                    employeeRank1Information.DisplayMemberPath = "YearsInCompany";

                    employeeRank1Information.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

                    employeeRank1Information.ItemsSource = employeeRank1InformationTable.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // show what is the error
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass `Id` as a parameter, I assume that is the primary key? Also, you should dispose your connection object with `using`.

Comment: Yes, **Id** is the primary key. Can you please elaborate on how to pass **Id** as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared where conditions for these without value

```
AND Salary = @salary AND
Responsibility = @responsibility AND
Position = @position AND
Age = @age AND
YearsInCompany = @yearsInCompany
```

You need to Fille them before executing the query

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", <VALUE FROM TABLE>);
```

Since you have not specified how you fill the gridview or table,
you need to get the following values yourself

Your SQL query contains 6 Conditions.

```
select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = @name AND Salary = @salary AND Responsibility = @responsibility AND Position = @position AND Age = @age AND YearsInCompany = @yearsInCompany.
```

but you have only filled one using -

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", employeeRank1List.SelectedValue);
```

so basically the query is equal to this when clicking on a list item

```
select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = <LitsView Item>
AND Salary = UNDEFINED  
AND Responsibility = UNDEFINED 
AND Position = UNDEFINED 
AND Age = UNDEFINED  
AND YearsInCompany = UNDEFINED;
```

now UNDEFINED here makes it a SQL syntax error since the scalar variables are missing. to get it to work, here is a workaround for you to understand how it works-

change this line in your code

```
string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = @name AND Salary = @salary AND Responsibility = @responsibility AND Position = @position AND Age = @age AND YearsInCompany = @yearsInCompany";
```

to this

```
string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Id = @name";
```

after you try this it should work with inaccurate results. to make it work properly fill the rest of the where conditions in your SQL code

Also, use a primary/unique key to locate records instead of using @NAME

Comment: What do you mean by "you nead to file them before executing the query". What do I write in <VALUE FROM TABLE>. Sorry If my questions are not the smartest, but I am really confused.

Comment: i updated my answer since i couldn't comment it here. you really need to learn more about SQL and scalar variables before you jump into these kind of coding. use https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful and I learned a lot. I know that my SQL knowledge is lagging, but I need to do a project with it and have limited time. However, I managed to figure it out myself, posted my way of solving below.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass `Id` into the query, as that is the primary key of `Employee`

```cs
private void employeeRank1List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(employeeRank1List.SelectedValue == null)  // less nesting to flip the condition
        return;
    try
    {
        // only select the columns you need
        const string query = @"
select
    Id,
    Name,
    Salary,
    Position,
    Responsibility,
    Age,
    YearsInCompany
from EmployeeRank1 e
where e.Id = @id
";
        // always use a new connection and dispose it
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
        // Create an SqlCommand and connect to the database
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        {
            // always specify parameter type (and length for strings)
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ((DataRow)employeeRank1List.SelectedValue)["Id"];
            // how do you get the Id column??
            DataTable employeeRank1InformationTable = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                employeeRank1InformationTable.Load(reader);
            }
        } // close connection as quick as you can

        // you can only set one column to display
        employeeRank1Information.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        employeeRank1Information.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

        employeeRank1Information.ItemsSource = employeeRank1InformationTable.DefaultView;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // show what is the error
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful and I learned a lot. Passing id as the parameter made it work. I figured out an own way of doing it, posted in below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by having multiple listboxes instead of one. Moreover, in the query I selected the id only, which is the primary key and then added multiple try-catch blocks in order to fill those listboxes that I had created. A screenshot of the working program, as well as the code

**Program**
[image]

**Code**

```
// a method that shows information for employees that are rank 1
    private void ShowEmployeeRank1Information()
    {
        // use a try-catch, in case we run into an
        // error while digging into the database
        try
        {
            // create a query and select everything from "EmployeeRank1" table
            // except the Password and GenericPassword columns
            string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Id = @id";

            // Create an SqlCommand and connect to the database
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            // create a connection to the database and run sqlCommand
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            // use the sqlDataAdapter
            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                // add a value to the EmployeesRank1 Information table, once an item in the EmployeesRank1 table is clicked
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", employeeRank1List.SelectedValue);

                // create a new data table that allows us
                // to store data from tables within objects
                DataTable employeeRank1PositionTable = new DataTable();

                // fill the sqlDataAdapter with all the
                // information from the query(from the EmployeeRank1 table)
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(employeeRank1PositionTable);

                // set the content of the employeeRank1List
                // to be the content from each column in the table
                employeeRank1PositionList.DisplayMemberPath = "Position";

                employeeRank1PositionList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

                employeeRank1PositionList.ItemsSource = employeeRank1PositionTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // show what is the error
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            // create a query and select everything from "EmployeeRank1" table
            // except the Password and GenericPassword columns
            string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Id = @id";

            // Create an SqlCommand and connect to the database
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            // create a connection to the database and run sqlCommand
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            // use the sqlDataAdapter
            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                // add a value to the EmployeesRank1 Information table, once an item in the EmployeesRank1 table is clicked
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", employeeRank1List.SelectedValue);

                // create a new data table that allows us
                // to store data from tables within objects
                DataTable employeeRank1AgeTable = new DataTable();

                // fill the sqlDataAdapter with all the
                // information from the query(from the EmployeeRank1 table)
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(employeeRank1AgeTable);

                // set the content of the employeeRank1List
                // to be the content from each column in the table
                employeeRank1AgeList.DisplayMemberPath = "Age";

                employeeRank1AgeList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

                employeeRank1AgeList.ItemsSource = employeeRank1AgeTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // show what is the error
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            // create a query and select everything from "EmployeeRank1" table
            // except the Password and GenericPassword columns
            string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Id = @id";

            // Create an SqlCommand and connect to the database
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            // create a connection to the database and run sqlCommand
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            // use the sqlDataAdapter
            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                // add a value to the EmployeesRank1 Information table, once an item in the EmployeesRank1 table is clicked
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", employeeRank1List.SelectedValue);

                // create a new data table that allows us
                // to store data from tables within objects
                DataTable employeeRank1ResponsibilityTable = new DataTable();

                // fill the sqlDataAdapter with all the
                // information from the query(from the EmployeeRank1 table)
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(employeeRank1ResponsibilityTable);

                // set the content of the employeeRank1List
                // to be the content from each column in the table
                employeeRank1ResponsibilityList.DisplayMemberPath = "Responsibility";

                employeeRank1ResponsibilityList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

                employeeRank1ResponsibilityList.ItemsSource = employeeRank1ResponsibilityTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // show what is the error
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        try
        {
            // create a query and select everything from "EmployeeRank1" table
            // except the Password and GenericPassword columns
            string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Id = @id";

            // Create an SqlCommand and connect to the database
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            // create a connection to the database and run sqlCommand
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            // use the sqlDataAdapter
            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                // add a value to the EmployeesRank1 Information table, once an item in the EmployeesRank1 table is clicked
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", employeeRank1List.SelectedValue);

                // create a new data table that allows us
                // to store data from tables within objects
                DataTable employeeRank1YearsInCompanyTable = new DataTable();

                // fill the sqlDataAdapter with all the
                // information from the query(from the EmployeeRank1 table)
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(employeeRank1YearsInCompanyTable);

                // set the content of the employeeRank1List
                // to be the content from each column in the table
                employeeRank1YearsInCompanyList.DisplayMemberPath = "YearsInCompany";

                employeeRank1YearsInCompanyList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

                employeeRank1YearsInCompanyList.ItemsSource = employeeRank1YearsInCompanyTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // show what is the error
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void employeeRank1List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(employeeRank1List.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            ShowEmployeeRank1Information();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have the same code 3 times. You could just return one `DataTable` and reference it in all 3 places. Also you need to create and dispose your connection, do *not* cache it.